# How to Get Audio Out via the Wolfson WM8731 CODEC on the Altera DE2-115 educational FPGA board?

Tags: audio, vhdl, intel-fpga

My group and I are trying to create a synthesizer out of a DE2-115 board for our undergraduate capstone project.

The only thing we can't figure out is how to get the frequencies mapped to the "keys" outputted properly through the audio port on board. We've scoured the web and all provided documentation included the datasheets for the codec but we can't figure out how to get it to work properly in VHDL.

Has anyone ever worked with outputting audio through the WM8731 and if so, would they be willing to help us out?

Answer (score 1):

I did that some years ago, wasn't too hard, but I used a NIOS processor with SOPC builder.

I used the Altera University Program IP cores [available here](https://www.altera.com/support/training/university/materials-ip-cores.htm).

These cores provides different functionality related to the DE2 and possibly other altera sponsered-board.

According to my logs, I used 3 of these cores to make audio work.

The `altera_up_avalon_audio_and_video_config`, which is used to configure the audio CODEC chip at initialization.

The second IP provide data in/out interface with the audio chip: `altera_up_avalon_audio`.

The last one is `altera_up_avalon_clocks`. I can't remember exactly what it does, but as the name imply it's necessary for the clocking of the audio chip. I think it takes an input clock and generate a PLL to provide the right clock to the CODEC.

As I said, I used a NIOS processor, still according to my log, the C code I used is:

```
void audio_isr(void* context, alt_u32 id)
{
    const int len = 2682358;
    static signed char *ptr = test_snd;
    unsigned int x[128];

    alt_up_audio_dev *audio_dev = (alt_up_audio_dev *)context;

    unsigned int n = alt_up_audio_write_fifo_space(audio_dev, ALT_UP_AUDIO_RIGHT);

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        x[i] = 0x800000 + ((int)*ptr++) << 9;

        if (ptr > test_snd+len) {
            ptr = test_snd;
            printf("Done\n");
        }
    }

    alt_up_audio_write_fifo(audio_dev, x, n, ALT_UP_AUDIO_RIGHT);
    alt_up_audio_write_fifo(audio_dev, x, n, ALT_UP_AUDIO_LEFT);
}

static void audio_init(void)
{
    alt_up_audio_dev *audio_dev = alt_up_audio_open_dev (AUDIO_0_NAME);
    if ( audio_dev == NULL)
        printf ("Error: could not open audio device \n");
    else
        printf ("Opened audio device \n");
    alt_up_audio_reset_audio_core(audio_dev);
    alt_up_audio_disable_write_interrupt(audio_dev);
    alt_up_audio_disable_read_interrupt(audio_dev);

    alt_irq_register(AUDIO_0_IRQ, (void *)audio_dev, audio_isr);
    alt_up_audio_enable_write_interrupt(audio_dev);
}
```

I don't remember how well that worked. Well enough to deserve a commit, but it was still a test, so don't give it too much importance. My final code was way too complicated to present here.

Hopefully, this is enough to get you started on the right track, which is to use Altera's IP. These IP are clear-source AFAIR, so if you don't want the NIOS, it should be simpler to start from their source than from scratch.

Comment: This is a good, easy way to do this. Also, take a look at the DE2-115 Media Computer ([altera directory]\University_Program\NiosII_Computer_Systems\DE2-115\DE2-115_Media_Computer\vhdl if you have the University tools installed) for examples on the correct pins and hooking everything up.
There's also example C code to run it in DE2-115_Media_Computer\app_software_HAL\media_HAL

Answer (score 1):

Probably you might require 3 modules, clock generator, audio configuration and audio serializer and deserializer. You no need to go for NIOS II based design. Plz check the altera lab experiment to understand how it works.

experiment link - https://www.altera.com/support/training/university/materials-lab-exercises.html#Digital-Logic-Exercises

pdf link - ftp://ftp.altera.com/up/pub/Altera_Material/Laboratory_Exercises/Digital_Logic/DE2-115/vhdl/lab12_VHDL.pdf.

also check for demo files